# I have created a new algorithm relating to finding all palindromes in a string. How to get it peer reviewed?

Tags: strings

I have created an algorithm to find all palindromes in a string, and studied the related theory (Manacher, Suffix trees) and prior work and don't think my algorithm relates to any of the existing ones, and the implementation of my algorithm is 3 times faster than a Manacher implementation.

Now I want to get it peer-reviewed and have people of the related field of study bear on it to see if it indeed holds any merit.

How should I proceed? I am not a student or affiliated to any educational institution currently.

In case this is not the right forum for this question, do let me know where I can take this to.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE.  I'm not sure your question is on-topic here.  Anyway, the way to get something published in a peer-reviewed conference/journal is to write a scientific paper and submit it to an appropriate conference/journal.  Your affiliation is unimportant.  Alternatively, if you just want to know whether it is correct, you potentially ask a separate question here where you show the algorithm and ask about its correctness.

Comment: Look at related questions on [Academia.SE](http://academia.stackexchange.com/). It might also be a good idea to talk to someone who has experience in publishing (in that field of study).

Comment: Thanks for the tips @D.W. & Juho. I am talking to my friends in academia. What I want to know are the names of the journals and conferences which the community here thinks might be relevant.

Comment: Bear in mind that a factor of three improvement might not be so interesting. In a couple of years' time, the existing algorithms will run three times faster because of Moore's law. And maybe it's just because you, naturally, put much more effort into optimizing the implementation of your own algorithm than the existing ones. Academic computer science is much more likely to be interested if the comparison between your algorithm and the existing ones gets better and better as the input gets longer (i.e., if your algorithm has better asymptotic running time).

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am collecting test cases from programming puzzles around the web and throwing at it, and it is linear on the input size so far. While I do all this, and with my query here and similar ones sent to my contacts, I want to hasten the fate of this algorithm and I can move on to the next thing.